# Different types of parameter in procedure insert statement

Tags: sql-server, database

I have 6 `Image` type parameters and one `nvarchar` but insert statement is not working.

```
Alter Procedure [dbo].[spGetImages]
    @img1 Image, @img2 Image, @img3 Image,
    @img4 Image, @img5 Image, @img6 Image,
    @Lname nvarchar(50)
As 
Begin 
    Insert into ImageData (Images, LoginName) 
    Values((@img1), (@img2), (@img3),
           (@img4), (@img5), (@img6), (@Lname))
End
```

**Error:**

> There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the `VALUES` clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Although this is simple statement but why I am getting this error?

Comment: There's quite a bit wrong with your DDL. For one, some of the parameters do not have declared data types in your DDL statement. Also, it's good that you want to do a fully qualified insert, i.e. explicitly list the columns. However, you need to have the same number fields in the value constructors.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to consider doing something like this:

```
alter proc dbo.spGetImages
    @img1 image,
    @img2 image,
    @img3 image,
    @img4 image,
    @img5 image,
    @img6 image,
    @Lname nvarchar(50)
as begin 

    insert into ImageData (Images, LoginName)
    values
        (@img1, @Lname),
        (@img2, @Lname),
        (@img3, @Lname),
        (@img4, @Lname),
        (@img5, @Lname),
        (@img6, @Lname);

end
```

Comment: @kamran, you should consider accepting an answer that has resolved your problem.

Comment: HI, I have another question regarding this procedure the question is how can I update Images column ?

Comment: You would want to create a stored procedure to handle that. With the current table structure it would be a bit difficult since there isn't any unique identifier besides the image itself.